# Java creating Class instance from another Jar with dependencies

Tags: java

I am trying to create an instance of a class from another jar, the problem is all the classes are different than the classes I have, so if I try to call a method requiring Test.class, I get an IllegalArgumentException

I've tried making a JarFile form the path, checked to make sure it's a class (I check every class in the jar), Make a URLClassLoader with the jar path and my jar path, loaded the class with the URLClassLoader, checked to make sure it has the right superclass, then store it in a list for later use.

Now I can't do anything with the subclass, I can't cast it to the superclass because it is loaded through another loader.

```
if(folder.listFiles() == null) return;
        for(File files : folder.listFiles()) {
            if(files.getName().endsWith(".jar")) {
                try {
                    JarFile jarFile = new JarFile(files.getAbsolutePath());
                    Enumeration<JarEntry> enumerator = jarFile.entries();

                    URL[] urls = {new URL("jar:file:" + files.getAbsolutePath() + "!/"), new URL("jar:file:" + CurrentClass.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation()
                            .toURI().getPath() + "!/")};
                    URLClassLoader cl = URLClassLoader.newInstance(urls);
                    while (enumerator.hasMoreElements()) {
                        JarEntry file = enumerator.nextElement();
                        if (file.isDirectory() || !file.getName().endsWith(".class")) {
                            continue;
                        }

                        String className = file.getName().substring(0, file.getName().length() - 6);
                        className = className.replace('/', '.');
                        Class clazz = cl.loadClass(className);
                        if(clazz.getSuperclass().getName().equals(MyClass.class.getName())) {
                            found.add(clazz);
                        }
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    logger.severe("Could not load jar at path: " + enchants.getPath());
                    logger.log(Level.SEVERE, e, () -> "Error:");
                }
            }
        }
```

The class returned isn't a subclass of the same Class, so I can't do much with it. How would I load it with the correct superclass? Or how could I cast it to the Superclass?

After more trial, I tried to avoid doing any casting but can't completely avoid it. If there is some way I can cast generically or something, that would work fine, I just need to save it to a list with other classes loaded from other jars.

Since this is unclear here is a better explanation

Jar A needs to create an instance of classes from jar B. The classes in jar B must be a subclass of a class in Jar A, because I add them to a list, and I can't add it as a dependency.

Comment: Can you give a clearer explanation of your problem? Usually you would add the jar as a dependency of your project and then you would instantiate the class of that library.

Comment: I tried explaining more, basically I have no idea what jars will be used, I just know they extend a certain class, and I need to get them as a subclass of that class and put them into a list.

Comment: What java version are you using? Since the introduction of the module system, in [project jigsaw](https://openjdk.java.net/projects/jigsaw/quick-start), the way to dynamically load classes may be different with regard to what you are trying to do.

Comment: I am using Java 1.8 as the libraries I use require it. Basically, I don’t know what jars are going to be there so I can’t package the jar with the dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry about the vagueness, I figured out I have to pass the original classloader to the child classloader to give it the correct Class instance of the original Superclass.